# Can't complete the stripe checkout form fields after redirection

Tags: javascript, testing, cypress

On my project, we have a stripe pricing table where the user can click a button to create a subscription and it redirects to this URL
https://checkout.stripe.com/c/pay/cs_test_a1UgwwtQ7POyL3aTstzchdzMxtZl5FvPk0mCfzLeSA0ZP0ToSd95KsZ240#fidkdWxOYHwnPyd1blpxYHZxWjZON1xqRnIyTGFuRDRGU0drb2AwX0NSMTU1fG0xcFYxTG0neCUl

Where cs_test is a unique value for each customer and it's created when the button is clicked.
The issue is when the new page is opened, cypress commands don't work

I found a web where the same behavior can be replicated https://stripe-tinydemos-pricing-table.glitch.me/

This is the stripe page opened:
[image: stripe-checkout]

This is my code:

```
    it.only('should open the stripe checkout page', function(){
           cy.visit('https://stripe-tinydemos-pricing-table.glitch.me/')
            cy.get('stripe-pricing-table[pricing-table-id="prctbl_1LPkKBAPEf9EarUkgSuVM4vY"]').shadow().find('iframe', {timeout:5000})
                .its('0.contentDocument.body').should('not.be.undefined')
                .then(cy.wrap)
                .find('div[data-testid="price-column"]').eq(1)
                .find('button').click()
            cy.origin('https://checkout.stripe.com/', () => {
                cy.get('input[name="shippingName"]').click().type('Ana');
            });
        });
```

cy.origin doesn't work, so I can't complete the fields.
If you could help me, please